# Как сделать скролл захватом курсора?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css-animation

Здравствуйте знатоки, интересует вопрос. Как сделать скролл захватом курсора. Например как [тут в слайдере](http://simpleopencart.com/). Но, у меня не слайдер, а линейный список(меню).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Или же как в варианте с [гуглом](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDloq1-pDZAhXMtxQKHZimCY8Q_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=903).

Comment: Ну, в слайдерах (точно могу говорить, например, за slick) перелистывание курсором предусмотрено изначально - там ничего не надо дополнительно делать.

Comment: А как сделать такое для меню, что бы можно было перетягивать элементы меню из стороны в сторону?

Comment: делаете слайдер, где в качестве слайдов выступают пункты меню (или группы пунктов - всё зависит от задумки)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону slick slider. Общий блок объявляете в js. Внутри делаете блоки со списками.

> http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```
  $('.название обёртки списка').slick({
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true
  });
```